# What is the length of the hour hand divided by the length of the second hand?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A clockmaker wants to design a clock such that the area swept by each hand (second, minute, hour) in one minute is the same (all hands move continuously). What is the length of the hour hand divided by the length of the second hand?

**Attempt**

We have that $\pi r_s^2 = \dfrac{1}{60}\pi r_m^2 = \dfrac{1}{3600} \pi r_h^2$. Thus, $\dfrac{r_h}{r_s} = \sqrt{3600} = 60$. The answer to this question was actually $\sqrt{720}$, so I am confused where I went wrong.

Comment: That should be $\pi r_s^2 = \dfrac{1}{60}\pi r_m^2 = \dfrac{1}{720} \pi r_h^2$, because the minute hand completes $12$ full revolutions for each revolution of the hour hand. (Ignore my previous comment!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hour hand takes $12$ hours to sweep a complete circle. During this time the second hand makes $12\times 60=720$ circuits. Therefore the area swept by the second hand must be $\frac{1}{720}$ of the area swept by the hour hand.

In other words, the relevant numbers are "how many turns of the minute hand per turn of the hour hand", and "how many turns of the second hand per turn of the minute hand". But it is *immaterial* how many seconds there are in a minute -- no matter how many small units we divide the minute into, the second hand needs to move by the same angular velocity, namely one revolution per *minute*.

Answer (score 1):

Why $3600$, that should be $12\cdot 60$.

Comment: There are $60$ minutes in an hour.

Comment: @user19405892 Correct. There are 60 minutes in an hour, so 60 revolutions of the second hand in one revolution of the minute hand. But then there are only 12 hours in a revolution of the hour hand, see.

Comment: For every revolution the second hand makes, the minute hand makes $\dfrac{1}{60}$ a revolution. Now since there are $3600$ seconds in an hour, we have the hour hand to complete $\dfrac{1}{3600}$ of a revolution.

Comment: @user19405892: It doen't matter how many seconds there are -- only how many _revolutions_ (which take one minute each) the second hand makes in one hour.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I don't understand how many seconds there are doesn't matter. It is a ratio of the number of revolutions.

Comment: @user19405892: Suppose, for example we have decided to divide the minute into 117 shorter seconds instead of the 60 usual ones. Then we would need 117 marks around the face of the clock in order to read the second hand. But the second hand would still take exactly one minute to complete a full circle. The number of seconds in a minute determine _only_ where the marks on the clock face are, _not_ how fast the hand moves.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I am taking into account the speed by saying how many seconds are in an hour. They move relative to that. In order for my answer to be wrong there has to be something wrong with my reasoning. What is wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: @user19405892: What is wrong with your reasoning is that what determines the speed of the second hand is that **it must have completed a full revolution after one minute**. So if will turn around 60 times in an hour. We can make the very same hand, operating at the very same speed, into a half-second hand by drawing twice as many marks around the perimeter of the clock -- or we can make it into a half-minute hand by caring only about when it passes the top or the bottom of the face. **The speed of the fastest hand is the same** no matter how few or how many units we divide its circle into.

Comment: In one minute obviously the second hand traces exactly $\pi r_s^2$. Thus, the hour hand covers the same area in one minute. Thus in $1$ minute the hour hand moves $\dfrac{1}{3600}$ of a circle and we have $\dfrac{1}{3600}\pi h^2$. Thus setting those equal we get what I had. I don't see what is wrong with this.

Comment: @user19405892: You're wrong when you claim that the hour hand covers $\frac1{3600}$ of the circle one minute. It takes $12\times 60=720$ minutes for the hour hand to make a complete revolution, so in one minute it covers $\frac{1}{720}$ of the circle.

Comment: I mean to say that the hour hand covers $\dfrac{1}{60*12}$ of the circle in one minute.

Comment: @user19405892: Yes, and $\frac{1}{60\times 12}$ is the same as $\frac{1}{720}$. Since the second hand covers $\frac{1}{1}$ of the circle in one minute, the disk it sweeps needs to have $720$ times as large area.

Comment: I see what I did wrong. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $\omega_h$, $\omega_s$ the angular velocity of the hour hand and the second hand, respectively, and let $r_h$, $r_s$ be their radii. If they must sweep out the same area in equal times we have to require that
$${1\over2} r_s^2\>\omega_s={1\over2} r_h^2\>\omega_h\ .$$
It follows that
$${r_h\over r_s}=\sqrt{\omega_s\over\omega_h}=\sqrt{\mathstrut720}\ ,$$
since the second hand performs $720$ cycles in the $12$ hours the hour hand takes to perform one cycle.